# StarkGate Alpha finalize the transfer from Starknet to Ethereum

Tags: starknet

I recently tried to bridge my funds from Starknet to Ethereum by StarkGate. Unfortunately When popup appeared to finalize the transaction I rejected it and my funds are stuck on the bridge. Is there any way to reenter this transaction and finish withrawing the funds?

[Transaction status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVJkF.png)

I read about the possibility of withdrawing funds via etherscan.io but I'm not sure how to do this correctly.